# MongoDB regex query to find unicode replacement character

Tags: regex, unicode, mongodb

I am trying to manually fix some documents in my Mongo database which contain the Unicode replacement character (looks like a question mark, see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm). I already fixed the issue why these characters ended up there but would like to keep the old data too. So all I want is a simple query which returns all documents containing this character.

What I came up with so far is

```
db.songs.find({artist: /\ufffd/});
```

to find all songs with an artist name containing the replacement character. No luck so far.

Comment: This is due to the fact that this is a representation when you cannot properly view the characters.  Mongo handles UTF-8 properly so it is not likely that this is your data, it is your view on it.

Comment: Yes, I know that and this is my data because I had some encoding bug that ended up in some of these replacement characters. That's why I want to go through the data and replace those manually with the right character. And to do that, I would like to view all entries that I need to edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems it doesn't like `\uXXXX` in the regexp. Try:

```
db.songs.find({artist: new RegExp("\ufffd")});
```

Comment: I had to use `'` instead of `"` on a Mac but yay, this worked!

Answer (score 1):

To bump an old thread :D for regex you need to escape the backslash otherwise it will escape the u instead:

`db.songs.find({artist: /\\ufffd/});`