# how can I query for unicode characters in mongodb using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

Let's say I have a record in my database that has:

```
name: "World\u0092s Greatest Jet Fighter Pilot"
```

OK I need to get in there and clean out the `\u0092` (there were a ton of these in the db). I can query like this:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
...
def self.by_partial name 
  return Movie.find(:all, :conditions => {:name => /^.*#{name}.*/i})
end


# console: 
>> sel = Movie.by_partial(/Greatest/) and sel.size
=> 1
```

and get back the correct number of records. But when I throw in the unicode, it fails:

```
>> sel = Movie.by_partial(/\u0092/) and sel.size
=> 0
>> sel = Movie.by_partial(/\\u0092/) and sel.size
=> 0
>> sel = Movie.by_partial('\u0092') and sel.size
=> 0
>> sel = Movie.by_partial('\\u0092') and sel.size
=> 0
```

What do I need to do to be able to query for records that contain unicode characters? Is this a setting in the rails console? I managed to solve this by iterating the records and checking like so `if mov.name =~ /\u0092/ ...` but I can't figure out how to pass a unicode string into my mongoid selector. Iterating the records seemed way too brute force. Luckily I don't need to do this very often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your problem is with Unicode, your problems are:

1. The string interpolation inside `by_partial`.
2. And `\u` only works inside double quoted strings.

Second things first:

```
> '\u0070'
=> "\\u0070" 

> '\\u0070'
=> "\\u0070" 

> "\u0070"
=> "p"
```

So `Movie.by_partial("\u0092")` should work.

Your first problem is that you're passing `/\u0092/` (which does match the character in question) to `by_partial` but `by_partial` does this:

```
/^.*#{name}.*/i
```

And `/^.*#{/\u0092/}.*/i` and that ends up as `/^.*(?-mix:\u0092).*/i`. I'd guess that the MongoDB driver is having some issues translating that Ruby regex into a JavaScript regex.

The MongoDB driver doesn't seem to like `\u` in a regex at all. Feeding `/^\u0070/` into MongoDB doesn't get me any matches but `/^p/` does find what I'm expecting, `/^#{"\u0070"}/` also works. I'm not sure what's going on in the guts of the MongoDB regex translator but [we're not the only ones to come across this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7561609/479863). I'd guess that the MongoDB regex translator doesn't understand `\u` so it ends up being converted to a raw `\\u0092` and since you don't have that sequence of six characters in your database, you don't find anything.

Comment: Sweet, all it needed was the double quotes. Thanks!